# Feature is required

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is not related to a specific problem.Rather refers to the style of programming.
  In all the articles and books that I have read says that you should not use global variables if you do not really need.For this reason, I prefer to use #define instead of const variable type in the global space.But #defines have a terrible flaw cannot be placed in namespaces.

I often want  c++ to have feature, which allows such behavior, something like #define in namespaces.

Example:

```
namespace Space
{
replace type variable = constructor(args);
replace type2 variable2(args);
}

void function(type variable);

int main()
{
    function(Space::variable);
}
```

Where "replace" is the identifier for that feature.And variables of that kind must be replace with his value compile time.

My questions:
1) How people achieve beautiful and clear code without using global constants
2) How I can suggest this idea to c++ standard  (optional)
3) Where is shortcomings of the idea  (optional)

Comment: A constant is not a variable.

Comment: constants at global scope are static by default, and are constant, so do not cause the same problems as global variables. Stop using `#define` and your problem goes away

Comment: `(static) const type variable` would work for your examples, no? Possibly even `(static) constexpr type variable`.

Comment: @jogojapan, the `static` is redundant

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, true. But with `static` you can put the declarations into a class definition, which in many cases gives you the namespace-effect.

Comment: Or just put them in a namespace, which gives you "the namespace effect" without needing a separate out-of-class definition as well

Comment: @JonathanWakely Separating declaration and definition can be useful / required for other purposes too. In any case, sometimes it makes sense to put the constant into a class, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The important thing here is that you've blindly accepted that "global variables suck" without knowing why. The problem is not global variables themselves, but global state. If you have global state, you introduce a dependency to every single bit of your code. A function does not have to express that it is going to use your global state through its signature, it can just use it. That means functions can behave differently between consecutive calls. A static constant (whether global or not) is not global state because it cannot change. It is no more a problem to your program than the number `5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mistaking a general rule against global shared *state* as a rule against global *variables*.  Since constants are immutable, they don't constitute state and they're perfectly safe to use.  Rather, the rule should be that all global variables *should be `const`*.

Answer (score 9):

> 1) How people achieve beautiful and clear code without using global constants

Just use global constants. Macros suck.

> 2) How I can suggest this idea to c++ standard (optional)

Don't.  There's already been a better [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1062.pdf) that was rejected.

> 3) Where is shortcomings of the idea (optional)

Macros suck. Don't use them like this, then you don't need changes to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

- Global `const` is much better than `#define`. `#define` is not regulated by `namespace` and is known to cause obscure problem (although, most of which are caused by *function-like* macro ).
- The best thing about `const` is that **it is regulated by namespaces** (as you mentioned).

I often use:

```
class SomeClass
{
  public:
    const static int STATIC_VALUE = 3;
};
const int SomeClass::STATIC_VALUE;//definition
```

Comment: You need a definition for that variable, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_static_const_definition

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry for the typo. I was distracted by the fact that *it did not get properly indented!* <s>I don't see why</s> Somehow it works now...

Comment: You still need a definition, see the link I gave

Comment: @JonathanWakely only if it's odr-used; although if you don't understand what odr-use is then you should always provide a definition.